# how to increment and decrement any item by clicking on a image view in android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am  making a restaurant applicaton...and i have to make this app...the link is here http://www.orderwizard.mobi/screenshots.htm ....but i stuck at this part..

[image: http://www.orderwizard.mobi/screenshots/android/order.png]

...
can u tell me how to increase and decrease quantity after clicking on a image view ...I have already put images in a list view..

Answer (score 2):

You van add  OnClickListener to you imageView as below

```
one= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.urImageView);

      one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View view) {
           //your code here,
           quantity++;
          }});
```